# How do I add a touch and hold gesture to my node in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, touch

I have this game where my node is in the middle of the screen and if I hold the left part of the screen the node will move to the left and if I hold on the right part of the screen the node will move to the right. I tried everything but cant seem to get it to work. Thank you! (I have some code but its not doing what I want it to do. If you want to see it and what it does ill put it up.)

EDIT CODE:

```
    var location = touch.locationInNode(self)

    if location.x < self.size.width/2 {
        // left code
        let moveTOLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-300, y: 0, duration: 0.6)
        hero.runAction(moveTOLeft)
    }
    else {
        // right code
        let moveTORight = SKAction.moveByX(300, y: 0, duration: 0.6)
        hero.runAction(moveTORight)


    }
```

Comment: Some code will be helpful but if all you want to do is touch and hold, just put a timer inside touches begin, then do something in touches end if the timer has run long enough.

Comment: I have some code can you take a look at it and tell me what Im doing wrong? Its only moving to the right wherever I touch the screen. Ill put the code in the op.

Comment: I added code to the op

Comment: @BeauYoung - I've reverted your edit. The bracket you removed was closing the final `if` statement; it wasn't a stray

Comment: Can you update the question too so things are a little more clearer as to what is and isn't working? From the code you've posted it look like it moves left when pressing on the screen, but moves right when NOT pressing on the screen, is that correct?

Comment: Yes have you played the game run bird run. I want that type of touch for my game https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/run-bird-run/id951346475?mt=8

Comment: if you see that game it is exactly what I want. I just cant figure it out which is frustrating.

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: My code only moves to the right when I touch anywhere on the screen. I dont know why I  cant get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do a check on the position of your touch in each update to determine the direction you want your character to move.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    var point = touch.locationInView(self)
    touchXPosition = point.x
    touchingScreen = true
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    touchingScreen = false
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if touchingScreen {
        if touchXPosition > CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) {
            // move character to the right.
        }
        else {
            // move character to the left. 
        }
    }
    else { // if no touches.
        // move character back to middle of screen. Or just do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: what did you declare touchXPosition as?

Comment: The left and right part of the screen dont move the node. I could hold any part of the screen and the node will still move to the right.

Comment: Update your code? What I've given you should be working. I just want to make sure you haven't still got that moveToRight in the else{} at the end of the update function.

Comment: Are you talking about the SKAction. And what code do I put in the if else statement than?

Comment: I have comments there telling you what code to put in there. You should only be moving the object IF touchingScreen is true. In your code, you had the object moving right even when there were no touches.  If you don't want the object doing anything, put nothing in the last else statement.

Comment: No there wasnt any movements when there was no touches. It only moved when I had a finger on the screen.

Comment: Do you have that link that you posted earlier?

Comment: I got it to work but it takes a sec before it starts to move. I did it with the SKAction. Ill post it in the op.

Comment: have you tried incrementing/decrementing the x positon by 1, and setting the duration to 0, to get more accurate left/right movement? My guess is that it can take a sec because the object is already moving 300 in another direction? That would give the object a movement of 60px per second. If you want it to be 600 per second, set the movement to 10.